# Laravel 5.1 Login Session Message

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to add a Session success message when a User login.

I've tried adding the following to the AuthenticatesUsers.php trait postLogin():

```
if (Auth::attempt($credentials, $request->has('remember'))) {
    return $this->handleUserWasAuthenticated($request, $throttles)->withSuccess("message");
}
```

I've also tried adding to the handleUserWasAuthenticated():

```
return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath())->withSuccess("message");
```

I run composer dump-autoload after each change but it just will not flash the message in the view. I use a partial called success.blade.php and the contents are:

```
@if (Session::has('success'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
        <strong>
            <i class="fa fa-check-circle fa-lg fa-fw"></i> Success. &nbsp;
        </strong>
        {{ Session::get('success') }}
    </div>
@endif
```

I think I'm missing something but I can't think what at the moment so hoping for a fresh set of eyes.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: did you try debugging it before it gets the partial view? somewhere in the main view, before your include the subview, do something like `{{ dd(session('success')) }}` to check to see if it exists there

Comment: Thank you @AndrewMalinnkov for your help. Although not needed I hadn't thought of this and will remember in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `->withSuccess()`.

Use `->with('success', 'Success message')`, as described in http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/responses#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data, or use the session manager. To access the session manager, you can use the `Request` object:

```
$request->session()->flash('success', 'Success message');
```

See http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/session#flash-data. You can also access the session manager using the `Session` facade:

```
Session::flash('success', 'Success message');
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm sure I tried it but for some reason it just didn't work yesterday. The only thing is that session()->flash(); doesn't work with redirect().